# Why signal can not be caught in the module in Perl

Tags: perl

I set the global signal handler in the main program.
The signal can be caught only after the `sleep_func` in `module.pm` is finished. 
When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, The signal handler doesn't take any effect in `sleep_func`.

I'd expect this to work like in a C program. Does anyone know how I can implement it?

I used `local $SIG{INT}=...`, but that does not work.

The main program:

```
use strict;
$SIG{INT}=sub {print "sigint caught in main"};
require "module.pm";
sleep_func();
sleep 10;
```

The module.pm:

```
use strict;

sub sleep_func {
    sleep 10;
}
1;
```

Comment: Works for me (on v5.16), in all variations (your code as well as with a normal package). But: do you really have to `require` modules (and not `use` them), and must it be a file with subs instead of a `package` (it isn't a `package` if what is shown are the exact programs and they work).  Also, nice that you have `use strict` but `use warnings` must be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason it doesn't work is because you are [suffering from buffering](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).
The signal is probably being caught, and the signal handler is probably running, but you don't see the output until the end of the program because Perl is buffering the output.

Some fixes are

- to append "\n" to the output in your signal handler -- standard output to a terminal is "line buffered" by default in Perl, so Perl will flush the output buffer when it sees a newline

  ```
  $SIG{INT} = sub { print "sigint caught in main\n" };
  ```
- to set `$|=1` in your script -- this enables autoflushing on standard output

  ```
  $|=1; $SIG{INT} = sub { print "siging caught in main" };
  ```
- to write the output to standard error instead of standard ouptut -- standard error is autoflushed by default

  ```
  $SIG{INT} = sub { print STDERR "sigint caught in main" };
  ```

Comment: Yes. I forgot to flush. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

See [Perl::Unsafe::Signals#DESCRIPTION](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Unsafe::Signals#DESCRIPTION).

```
use Perl::Unsafe::Signals;
use strict;

sub sleep_func {
    UNSAFE_SIGNALS {
        sleep 10;
    }
}
1;
```

When (not if) this breaks, you get to keep the pieces.

Comment: That's new to me. Thank you.